# How to call a function inside of an Oracle package via SubSonic

Tags: oracle, subsonic

I've got an Oracle package that contains many functions.  In the package body, these functions can get very complex.  Is it possible for SubSonic to generate against specific functions inside of a package?

Right now if I have a package called ProjectData and there are functions in there such as GetEmail, CloneProject, GetProjectID, it will generate for every single one of those inside of 1 giant stored procedure.

I'd like to generate against just ProjectData.GetEmail but I'm not sure if this can be done or how to do it.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: which versions of SubSonic and Oracle are you using?

Comment: SubSonic 2.1.1 and Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that SS 2.x doesn't work against Oracle Packages - http://forums.subsonicproject.com/t/2508.aspx